# Multiple regression in Python

Tags: python, math, scipy, regression

I am currently using scipy's linregress function for single regression. I am unable to find if the same library, or another, is able to do multiple regression, that is, one dependent variable and more than one independent variable. I'd like to avoid R if possible. If you're wondering, I am doing FX market analysis with the goal of replicating one currency pair with multiple other currency pairs. Anyone help? Thanks,

Thomas

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the OLS class [http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/OLS] from the SciPy cookbook.

Comment: I think the relevant python reference should now be http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/regression.html installable through pypi

Comment: The reference in the above comment is now at http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/regression.html

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is what you need, but the [Modular toolkit for Data Processing (MDP)](http://mdp-toolkit.sourceforge.net/) libray recently implemented [multivariate linear regression](http://mdp-toolkit.sourceforge.net/node_list.html#mdp.nodes.LinearRegressionNode). It is under LGPL license.